# Search facebook public events by location

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, token

it's possible to search only **PUBLIC EVENTS**  by **location**?
I'm trying this:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3D%2A%26type%3Devent%26center%3D43.7228386%2C10.4016888%26distance%3D1000
```

but I found only my private events (and the results are not near to selected geo-center)..why?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Places: you can narrow your search to a specific location and distance
>   by adding the center parameter (with latitude and longitude) and an
>   optional distance parameter.
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

The location parameters, `center` and `distance`, are only useful when searching for places, not events.

If you want to get public events, don't search for `*`, otherwise Facebook couldn't give back the entire list of its events! You should specify a keyword.

Your query becomes: `/search?q=KEYWORD&type=event`

Answer (score 2):

The [search documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/) lists all available search options - searching for events at a location within a radius of a set of coordinates is not one of the available options